# BroadcastServiceProvider.php and broadcaster.php issues after Laravel 5.4 upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm a bit of a noob; forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have this class in my app to set up broadcast channels (for Pusher):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Thread;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api', 'jwt.auth']]);

        /*
         * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
         */
        Broadcast::channel('users.*.threads', function ($user, $userId) {
            return $user->obfuscated_id == $userId;
        });

        Broadcast::channel('threads.*', function ($user, $threadId) {
            return $user->can('participate', Thread::findByObfuscation($threadId));
        });

        Broadcast::channel('notifications.*', function ($user, $notifiableId) {
            return $user->obfuscated_id == $notifiableId;
        });

        Broadcast::channel('messages.*', function ($user, $userId) {
            return $user->obfuscated_id == $userId;
        });
    }
}
```

This was working fine on Laravel 5.3 but, after an upgrade (using Laravel Shift) to 5.4, I started getting the error:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(), 1 passed in /home/vagrant/Development/Peeps/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php on line 68 and exactly 2 expected in /home/vagrant/Development/Peeps/api/app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php:35
```

Comparing the previous and new versions of the Broadcaster.php file, there are a few changes, most suspiciously, this line:

```
$parameters = $this->extractAuthParameters($pattern, $channel, $callback);
```

which now passes an extra parameter, $callback.

I think it is something to do with the way the callback functions are passed along the stack and am wondering if there's a better way to write the BroadcastServiceProvider.php that will be more friendly to the updated Illuminate classes.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think shift missed a step. Plz follow this to get this solved.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

When defining channel name placeholders in Laravel 5.3, the * character is used. In Laravel 5.4, you should define these placeholders using {foo} style placeholders, like routes:

```php
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
});
```